# Active state in navigation bar (CSS only)

Tags: html, css

Currently I´m highlighting the `active` tab in my site with just a `CSS` class,
the problem is that I´m having more and more tabs and this list is getting bigger and every time I add a new tab I also need to add a new selector to the class

Is there a `CSS` only way to simplify this?

```
body.students li.students,
body.teachers li.teachers,
body.sports li.sports,
...,
... {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

I´m adding the class to the body for each section
is there a way to do something like this with CSS?

```
body.[class] > li.[class] {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Basically I *just* want to add a property if both (body and li) have the same class

Example for **students.html**

```
<body class="students">
    <ul>
        <li class="students">students</li>
        <li class="teachers">teachers</li>
</body>
```

In this example `li.students` is the one that will be highlighted

Example for **teachers.html**

```
<body class="teachers">
    <ul>
        <li class="students">students</li>
        <li class="teachers">teachers</li>
</body>
```

In this example `li.teachers` is the one that will be highlighted

Thanks!

Comment: Show some HTML....

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189536/html-css-navigation-active-state @handsome

Comment: Are you talking about different pages?

Comment: Not possible with css only.. you need jquery to do this

Comment: You are already doing it correctly. What's the problem?

Comment: A simpler way could be .teachers .teachers {} or .students .students{} . This should work also

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML code - introduce a class "current_page" (or whatever you'd like to call it)

```
<body class="students">
    <ul>
        <li class="students current_page">students</li>
        <li class="teachers">teachers</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Or

```
<body class="teachers ">
    <ul>
        <li class="students">students</li>
        <li class="teachers current_page">teachers</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

That way, you'll only ever need one selector:

```
li.current_page {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

You could also do it in JavaScript if you don't like to change your HTML code:

```
var classname = document.querySelector("body").className;
var li = document.querySelector("li." + classname);
li.className = li.className + " current_page";
```

Comment: this is the obvious way. I want to explore something more savage

Comment: and this will require to have multiple headers. and I only have one and I want to avoid adding some logic on it.

Comment: @handsome: I added a JavaScript solution.